# Swap 2 letter part of a url in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is my htaccess file (complete). What I need to do is rewrite it so that images for say /uk/images/file.jpg become /images/uk/file.jpg. Although its not erroring its not working either. Am I missing something?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z]{2})/images/(.*)$ /images/$1/$2 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|jscript|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The leading slash in the pattern has to be removed, it does not make sense in `.htaccess` style files. Those work on _relative_ paths. That is actually correct in the condition below, so the file is inconsistent in this currently.

Comment: What do u mean its not working? what happens when u type the url?

Comment: I'm using codeigniter but I get a 404 page.

Comment: Does "/image/uk/file.jpg" ? exist on your server?

Comment: Unfortunately removing the leading slash also fails to work

Comment: Yes starkeen it does - but the folder is uppercase!! I wonder if thats it

Comment: When you enter any other url  does that go to index.php?

Comment: Yes - it is rewritten to go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z]{2})/images/(.*)$ /images/$1/$2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/([^/]+)/ [NC]

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|jscript|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```